# Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3 - 3x^2+1}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I want find the limit of $\frac{x^3 - 3x^2+1}{x^3}$ as $x\to 0$.

So I write

$$\frac{x^3 - 3x^2+1}{x^3} = 1 - \frac{3x^2 +1}{x^3}$$ and

$$\lim_{x \to 0^- }(\frac{x^3 - 3x^2+1}{x^3})= \lim_{x \to 0^-}(1 - \frac{3x^2 +1}{x^3})$$ Here, the limit must be  $\pm \infty$ and I think when $x \to 0^-$ as $x^2$ is something positive, $x^3$ is something negative and since we have $- \frac{3x^2 +1}{x^3}$ we should have $+\infty$. However, it must be  $-\infty$. Similarly I think $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^-}(1 - \frac{3x^2 +1}{x^3}) =-\infty$ but it's $+ \infty$.

What do I miss, how should I think?

Comment: Um, who says it's positive infinity from the left?$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac {x^3-3x^2+1}{x^3}=-\infty$$

Comment: My consideration says it's $+\infty $ as I explained in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a sign mistake,  $$\frac{x^3 - 3x^2+1}{x^3} = 1 - \frac{3x^2 \color{red}{-}1}{x^3}$$

Hence your conclusion is opposite.

Intuitively, as  $x \to 0^-$,  $x^2$ is **small** in magnitude and hence  $(3x^2-1)$ approaches $-1$, $x^3$ is something negative and it is small, so we have $- \frac{3x^2 +1}{x^3}$ goes to $-\infty$.

The left hand side limit goes to $-\infty$ while the right hand side limit goes to $+\infty$, hence the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Write $$f(x)=g(x)h(x),$$ where $$g(x)=x^3-3x^2+1,\quad h(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}.$$
Now, approaching from the right, we have $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}g(x)=1,\quad \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}h(x)=\infty.$$ Similarly, approaching from the left, we have $$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}g(x)=1,\quad\lim_{x\to 0^-}h(x)=-\infty.$$ The limits regarding $h(x)$ can be seen by looking at the [sketch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=L4K9WoXBCcrSgAb-2634AQ&q=1%2Fx%5E3&oq=1%2Fx%5E3&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0j0i7i30k1l2j0j0i7i30k1l3j0.8078.8277.0.8592.2.2.0.0.0.0.78.144.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.143....0.tjf0Vm_-qj8) for the corresponding graph.

Since the right hand/left hand limits aren't equal; $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for the edit; very sloppy mistake from myself.